# Creating Model for two different tables already existent - MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem using MVC.

I created a Model with name PO_Header that is the Purchase Order Header and other Model with name PO_Detail that  is the Purchase Order Details.

The problem is that I already have both Tables created in Database, PO_Header and PO_Detail but how could I create just one controller and Views for both Tables?

They are in different tables but I need to add them in the same Form so when I click Create/Add, both tables will be updated.

Model for PO_Header:

```
[Table("PO_Header")]
public class PO_Header
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Número Pedido")]
    public string PONumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Cliente")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    public virtual Customers customers { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Expedidor")]
    public string shipper { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("RTA")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime rta { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data de Envio")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime sendDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data de Criação")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime createDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("LI")]
    public int LI_Number { get; set; }
}
```

Model for PO_Detail:

```
[Table("PO_Detail")]
public class PO_Detail
{
    [DisplayName("Número Pedido")]
    public string PONumber { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PONumber")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual PO_Header poHeader { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DisplayName("Part Number")]
    public string partNumber { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [DisplayName("Line Number")]
    public int lineNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fabricante")]
    public int MakerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MakerID")]
    public virtual Makers makers { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Anuente")]
    public bool anuente { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Quantidade")]
    public int quantity { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fornecedor")]
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SupplierID")]
    public virtual Suppliers suppliers { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Valor Unitário")]
    public decimal? unitPrice { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Valor Total")]
    public decimal? totalPrice { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Moeda")]
    public int MoedaID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MoedaID")]
    public virtual Sigla_Moeda siglaMoeda { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need relationship between 2 tables. Please look at example here    http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/219d4d/working-with-multiple-tables-in-mvc-using-entity-framework/

Comment: And here's  great tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oN1f2Vpc-wU)